# PHP, find exact value from mysql arranged data

Tags: php

I have a data in My-Sql column like this

```
T_interest
1,14,49,145,203,302
```

It represents each value for personal interest keywords.

I tried to extract the value and distinguish whether it has the value or not for the checkbox.

```
if(strstr($u_interest['u_interest'], ','.$row['i_idx'])):
$selected = 'checked';
```

here is the php command that I use right now.

but it doesn't extract exact value from the database.

Let's say I want to check if the data has 14 number or from this user table

```
T_interest
1,14,49,145,203,302
```

and if I use above command it tells me that a user has two values.

```
14,145
```

It looks like PHP strstr command tells me two values because these two have 14 number.

So, can you help me why this is happening?

If you want more php lines I can post them.

Comment: check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138656/check-if-value-is-inside-string-that-has-values-separated-by-commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode it into an array, this way you get the individual values.

```
explode(",",$t_interest["u_interest"]);
```

Then you can test for equality much easier.

Comment: it makes a new array for the value. How to tell if the data has the number value or not?

Comment: awesome! I used in_array($value) to find whether it exist or not!. It works perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read up on [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). A properly normalized design would make this problem moot.

As for your question, since you're forced to use string operations, you'll have to check for multiple different cases:

1) the number you want is at the START of the string
2) the number you want is at the END of the string
3) the number you want is the ONLY number in the string
4) the number you want is in the MIDDLE of thee string:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE
    (T_Interest = 14) OR   // only number
    (T_Interest LIKE '14,%') OR /// at the begnning
    (T_Interest LIKE '%,14') OR // at the end
    (T_Insertest LIKE '%,14,%') // in the middle
```

Comment: if a column has one value, it would be much easier like this. the database has multiple numbers, and the key is how to find a exact number value from multiple numbers