# Check if value is inside string that has values separated by commas?

Tags: php

Is there a simple way to check if a value is inside a string?

```
$string = ' 123,456,789,abc789,def'
if ($string has '789') { 
   // code
}
```

I only want an exact match (so only 789, not abc789)

The only way I can think of doing it at the moment is to explode the string using the comma to turn it into an array and then check each value for a match. Is there a better/more efficient way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using strpos won't work if for example you have `' 123,456,789,12789,abc,def'`, use [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead :

```
$string = ' 123,456,789,abc789,def';
$what_to_find = '789';
if (preg_match('/\b' . $what_to_find . '\b/', $string)) { 
   // code
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/51939)

Comment: Wouldn't an explode + check if in array be more efficient than a preg_match?

Comment: No, regexp are very very very very very efficient for strings.

Comment: It is simpler than exploding to an array, so thanks for the solution :)

Comment: preg_match is much more flexible but runs slower, for this simple match strpos() worked well

Comment: Slower than splitting the string then using in_array()?

Comment: @OneOfOne No, like I said, more flexible, but slower than strpos() for this simple match

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary and would split `'one two,three'` into three elements.

Answer (score 3):

you could explode it and check if its in the array

```
function stringContains($string, $needle)
{
    $arr = explode(',',$string);
    if(in_array($needle,$arr))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

aside from the stpos suggestions, this will not return true if you're looking for 12 in a string 123,456 where strpos will return a position

Comment: I think this might be the best way after all, because I need it to be exact matches, thanks.

Comment: yeah and in array does the check for you so you dont have to manually check each array element for a match

Comment: @user2413333 If this is the best way, perhaps move the accepted tick to this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) function. It will return `FALSE` if the needle isn't found in the search string:

```
if (strpos($string, '789') !== FALSE) {
    // code...
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/51937)

---

If you want an exact match, then I'd use `explode()`:

```
$parts = explode(',', trim($string));
if (in_array('789', $parts)) {
    // code...
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/51940)

Comment: @Sbml: See the first part of my answer. It uses `strpos()` :)

Comment: Yes sorry, both options are case-sensitive. For case-insensitive you could add stripos() function: if (stripos($string, "ABC")) echo "Found!";

Comment: @Sbml: Yep, but it doesn't matter. The search string is `789`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `strpos()` function.

```
$string = ' 123,456,789,abc,def'
if (strpos($string,'789') !== FALSE) { 
   // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strpos` function which is used to find the occurrence of one string inside other

```
  $string = ' 123,456,789,abc,def';

 if (strpos($string,'789') !== false) {
        echo 'true';
    }
```

See [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version of @Bryan's code:

```
function stringContains($string, $needle) {
    return in_array($needle, explode(',', $string));
}
```